# Batch setting a title at the top

Tags: batch-file

How would I set a title to a batch file so it will say My Batch file at the top. thanks if any one can help. I have looked on google but I didn't find any thing of any use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this:

```
title "My Batch File"
```

Let me know if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a normal batch file then either use:

```
title "My Batch File"
```

to see the text appear in the window title bar

or use

```
@echo off
echo My Batch File 
@echo on
```

to have it appear inside the CMD prompt window.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@echo off
title Batch File
```