# Changing The Window Name In Batch

Tags: batch-file, window

I am currently creating a game and I want it to look really professional but the window name is "Command Prompt" how do I change that?

Comment: `title "New name"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch setting a title at the top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607485/batch-setting-a-title-at-the-top)

Answer (score 35):

Just use this line of code to change the title:

```
TITLE My new window title
```

Don't forget to check this answer as accepted if it works!